# Retrofit 2 - Manage http "204 No content" and "200" with content for the same request

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, rx-java2, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit 2 and OkHttp 3, with RxJava2

I'm doing a call to a server with some parameters. Base on the parameters, the server returns a JSON with a list of objects. But if there is nothing to return, instead of returning a JSON with an empty list, the server return '204 - No Content'. As a result I get a NullPointerException.

I know how to manage a JSON response, and I know how to manage a 204 response but not together for the same call.

I could use an interceptor, but as I have a lot of call, my Retrofit client is created once and then injected when necessary using Dagger2.

How can I manage this case?

Comment: Try to use Observable.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> empty())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @eurosecom suggestion I have solved my problem like described below. The only issue is I wanted the 'No Content' response, from the server, to be managed as a 'success' by Retrofit, but with this solution it's still managed as an error.

**Retrofit client**

```
return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new GeneralInterceptor(callback))
    .build


private static class GeneralInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    //... 

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder();
        Response response = chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());

        // Throw specific Exception on HTTP 204 response code
        if (response.code() == 204) {
            throw new NoContentException("There is no content");
        }

        return response; // Carry on with the response
    }
}
```

**In the Presenter**

```
mModel.performRequest()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
        if (throwable instanceof NoContentException) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }

        return Observable.error(throwable);
    })
    .subscribe(res -> {
        //... Manage the result
    }, throwable -> {
        //... On error
    }
);
```

Comment: I'll not mark this answer as accepted as it doesn't match the question requirements. I'd appreciate if somebody has a better solution.

Comment: Your solution is good, mark this answer as accepted. I have read interesting article about Handling null in RxJava 2.0 https://medium.com/@joshfein/handling-null-in-rxjava-2-0-10abd72afa0b May be help, but i did not test it.

Comment: If I remember the NullPointerException was coming from the Gson parser as it expected something and had a null content. But it actually can help me for another part of my app as I have already had to face the issue describe in the article you've linked. Thx for your help! I'll mark the answer as accepted then.

Comment: why not  return a modified Response object (using ```response.newBuilder()```) and change the response code and add an empty body? ```if (response.code() == 204) {
                        response = response.newBuilder()
                                .code(200)
                                .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "[]"))
                                .build()
                    }``` ?

Answer (score 1):

I use onErrorResumeNext for error response. For example

```
mSubscription.add(mViewModel.getMyPohybyFromSqlServer("3", drupoh)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> { Log.e(TAG, "Error xxx " + throwable.getMessage());
                hideProgressBar();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Server not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> empty())
            .subscribe(this::setPohyby));
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But what I'd like to do is Retrofit to call onSuccess as it's not supposed to be an error. 'Cause at the moment the throwable type is `NullPointerException` when there is no content, so I could resume on error as you suggest but the `NullPointerException` could be caused by an error in the code too so I find it dangerous to consider it only means the content was empty.